# How to update/replace deployment of Kubernetes in JAVA

Tags: java, deployment, kubernetes, updates

I use ConfigMap as Volume in the deployment.
I'm trying to update a deployment with different Volume and VolumeMount.(see example below)

I tried all the following ways:

(I use io.fabric8.kubernetes.api to do the operations on kubernetes.)

1)

> client().extensions().deployments().inNamespace(namespaceName).withName(deploymentName).**replace(deployment)**;

2)

> client().extensions().deployments().inNamespace(namespaceName).withName(deploymentName).**createOrReplace(deployment)**;

3)

> client().extensions().deployments().inNamespace(namespaceName).withName(deploymentName).**cascading(false).replace(deployment)**;

4)

> client().extensions().deployments().inNamespace(namespaceName).withName(deploymentName).*edit().editSpec().editTemplate().editSped().**removeAllFromVolumes(volumes)**.endSpec().endTemplate().endTemplate().endSpec().done()*;

5)

> client().extensions().deployments().inNamespace(namespaceName).withName(deploymentName).*edit().editSpec().editTemplate().editSped().**removeFromVolumes(volume)**.endSpec().endTemplate().endTemplate().endSpec().done()*;

All the above commands don't work!...

I also tried :

> client().extensions().deployments().inNamespace(namespaceName).withName(deploymentName).*edit().editSpec().editTemplate().editSped().**AddToVolumes(volume)**.endSpec().endTemplate().endTemplate().endSpec().done()*;

and it works.

i.e. only ADD works, but REMOVE doesn't work....

Is it a BUG or not ?
Did I use it in the right way?
I just want to update the deployment with different Volume (ConfigMap type) and VolumeMount, how should I do?
Thank you!

Example:
The old Deployment is like this: (I only show the main part)

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: d2
  namespace: n1
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: x.x.x.x
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: c2
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var
            name: configmapvolume1
          - mountPath: /var/a
            name: configmapvolume2
        volumes:
        - configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            items:
            - key: a.yml
              path: a.yml
            name: a
          name: configmapvolume1
        - configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            items:
            - key: c.yml
              path: c.yml
            name: a
          name: configmapvolume2
```

The new Deployment is like this:(I only show the main part)

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: d2
  namespace: n1
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        creationTimestamp: null
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: x.x.x.x
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: c2
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/b
            name: configmapvolume1
        volumes:
        - configMap:
            defaultMode: 420
            items:
            - key: b.yml
              path: b.yml
            name: b
          name: configmapvolume1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve found the reason. 
There was a parameter named "rollbackRevision" and it was set with value 0 in the `deployment` (the input of function `replace`).
Because of this parameter, the replace operation always rollback to the previous version.
After deleting this parameter (set it to null), the following function works well:
`client().extensions().deployments().inNamespace(namespaceName).withName(deploymentName).replace(deployment);`

Answer (score 1):

If you add --save-config when you create your deployment for the first time, you’ll be able to adjust its specification later:

```
kubectl create -f deploymentv1.yaml --save-config
```

To update it with adjusted yaml file run the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f deploymentv2.yaml
```

This way new pod will be created from the adjusted specification. The old pod will be terminated then.

I’ll update my answer when I figure out how to apply `--save-config` option using java code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to create a deployment using kubectl create -f deploymentv1.yaml --save-config, and then use java api to update it, but it didn't work. Do you know why? Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to update it with kubectl instead of java? I mean the exact same changes that you want to do using java?

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I've found the reason.